# Hadamard Product of $e^z-1$

Tags: complex-analysis, hadamard-product

Assuming the formulas $$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right),$$ I want to find the Hadamard product of $e^z-1$. I think I've done the work correctly, but I end up having an extra factor of $2\pi i$ at the end (this is from Stein and Shakarchi's book and they list the answer for this particular problem). So, my work is
\begin{align}
e^z-1&=e^{z/2}\left(e^{z/2}-e^{-z/2}\right)\\ \\
&=e^{z/2}\left(e^{i(-iz/2)}-e^{-i(-iz/2)}\right)\\ \\
&=2ie^{z/2}\left(\frac{e^{i(-iz/2)}-e^{-i(-iz/2)}}{2i}\right)\\ \\
&=2ie^{z/2}\sin(-iz/2)\\ \\
&=2\pi i ze^{z/2}\frac{\sin(-iz/2)}{\pi z}\\ \\
&=2\pi i ze^{z/2}\frac{\sin\left(\pi(\frac{-iz}{2\pi})\right)}{\pi z}\tag{$\ast$}\\ \\
&=2\pi i ze^{z/2}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{\left(\frac{-iz}{2\pi}\right)^2}{n^2}\right)\\ \\
&=2\pi i ze^{z/2}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{4n^2\pi^2}\right).
\end{align}

The answer according to the book is $$e^z-1=e^{z/2}z\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z^2}{4n^2\pi^2}\right).$$Have I made a simple mistake in calculation, or are the two somehow compatible with each other?

**Update:** Thomas Andrews has pointed out a mistake in my infinite product formula. I've corrected that mistake.

$(\ast)$ The error occurs from this line to the next. Instead of multiplying and dividing by $z$, I should have multiplied and divided by $\frac{-iz}{2\pi}$. That would cause the appropriate cancellation.

Comment: Well, your answer can't be right, since it gives an imaginary value for real $z$. Start from there.

Comment: I thing you've got the wrong value for $\sin \pi z/\pi$ - there needs to be a factor of $z$ in there to get $0$ when $z=0$.

Comment: I certainly am not disagreeing, I am just curious about where my logic went wrong.

Comment: Well, again, starting with the wrong formula doesn't help.

Comment: Actually, you haven't corrrected the mistake, because you've divided and multiplied by $\pi z$, when you want to divide and multiple by $\pi w$ where $w=\frac{-iz}{2\pi}$. You've essentially said that $$\frac{\sin (-iz/2)}{\pi z}$$ is the formula, but the formula there is wrong $-iz/2\neq \pi z$.

Comment: Haha, just pointed that out, actually.

Comment: You don't need to fix your question, by the way - fixing your question is actually bad form, because it means a later person reading your question doesn't see your mistake.  One purpose of the site is for other people to come and read questions later and learn - if the question is no longer a question, but just a correct set of steps, then you are breaking that usefulness in the site.

Comment: Oh, of course, that is why I didn't correct it (except the formula). I merely pointed out where the mistake occurred and elaborated how to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got the wrong product formula for $\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi}$. According to [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product):  $$\frac{\sin\pi z}{\pi z}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right)$$

Note the $z$ in the denominator.

You have:

$$e^z-1  =2ie^{z/2}\sin(-iz/2)$$

Letting $w=\frac{-iz}{2\pi}$ this is $\sin \pi w$ and we can substitute into:

$$\sin \pi w = \pi w\prod\left(1-\frac{w^2}{n^2}\right)$$

But notice $\pi w = -iz/2$. So this yields:

$$e^z -1 = 2i e^{z/2} (-iz/2) \prod_n \left(1+\frac{z^2}{4\pi^2 n^2}\right)\\= e^{z/2} z \prod_n \left(1+\frac{z^2}{4\pi^2 n^2}\right)$$