# How can I see $e^z-1=ze^{z/2}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+\frac{z^2}{4\pi^2k^2})$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to see why below equation holds.

$$
e^z-1=ze^{z/2}\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1+\frac{z^2}{4\pi^2k^2}\right)
$$

Just simply applying the Taylor series definition does not give a solution. What method can I use to see the statement is true?

Comment: this follows easily from the product formula for $\sin w$ with obvious substitutions, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: Try using Weierstrass' factorization theorem!

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/352147/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is $\sinh\frac{z}{2}=\frac{z}{2}\prod_k(1+\tfrac{z^2}{(2\pi k) ^2})$, or equivalently $\sin w=w\prod_k(1-\tfrac{w^2}{(k\pi)^2})$. This looks plausible given the roots of both sides and the expected small-$w$ asymptomatic behaviour, and the Weierstrass factorization theorem formalizes that intuition.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a track, I may edit my answer later and give a complete solution, but for now here's a hint :

1- Prove that for any $ \left(n,z\right)\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\times\mathbb{C} $, we have : $$ \sinh{z}=n\sinh{\left(\frac{z}{n}\right)}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(1+\frac{\sinh^{2}{\left(\frac{z}{2n}\right)}}{\sin^{2}{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)}}\right)} $$

2- Prove that the previous product does in deed converge to the infinite product of the limit of what's inside, meaning : $$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(1+\frac{\sinh^{2}{\left(\frac{z}{2n}\right)}}{\sin^{2}{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)}}\right)}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}{\left(1+\frac{z^{2}}{k^{2}\pi^{2}}\right)} $$

3- Conclude.