# How to represent $e^z -1$ as an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

This question was part of my complex analysis assignment and I am not getting ideas on how this question should be attempted.

> Express $e^z -1$ in an infinite product.

I an not able to even start solution of this as I don't know which result should be used. 1 thing i noticed that the function is entire $z=0$ is a zero.

Can you please help with some hints?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352147/hadamard-product-of-ez-1

Comment: If that really was all of the question, one could answer with $$e^z-1=z\,\prod^\infty_{n=1}\frac{e^{z/2^n}+1}2,$$ and that's not hardly what they wanted.